# RegEx to replace prefix and postfix

Tags: regex

I would like to build a RegEx expression to replace the prefix and postfix of a string. the general string is built from

1. a known prefix string
2. some letter a-z or A-Z
3. some unknown string with letters, hyphens, backslash, slash and numbers.
4. a hyphen
5. an integer number
6. the symbols #.
7. some string of letters

Examples:

```
KnownStringr/df-2e\d-3724#.Gkjsu
KnownStringEd\e4v-bn-824#.YKfg
KnownStringa-YK224E\yy-379924#.awws
```

I would like to replace the prefix and postfix of the NUMBER so that I get:

```
MyPrefix3724MyPostfix
MyPrefix824MyPostfix
MyPrefix379924MyPostfix
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a ready solution and shows no minimal efforts.

Comment: So basically, you need to get the integer number that is last before the # sign, am I correct? What have you tried so far? what language do you use?

Comment: I did try using online tools such as http://www.regexr.com/ but it is far too complicated for a beginner. I do need the last integer number before the # but only if it comes after KnownString. Also, I need to replace the entire sequence with a new sequence containing that integer. And I have to do that within the same regular expression. I don't even know if that's possible

Comment: You should always specify a language when you're asking a regex tag. Not only for variation in flavors (not a problem with this particular match) but the method to replace is quite different from language to language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do the trick, but you always should specify the language/framework you're using, because not all regex engines support the same features.

The number that you want to capture would be in capture group #3 (`(\d+)`), which most languages reference as \3

```
(?:KnownString)([a-zA-Z])(.*?)-(\d+)\#\.[a-zA-Z]+
```

Explanation:

```
 (?:                     # Opens NCG
     KnownString         # Literal KnownString
 )                       # Closes NCG
 (                       # Opens CG1
     [a-zA-Z]            # Character class (any of the characters within)
                           # Anything between a and z
                           # Anything between A and Z
 )                       # Closes CG1
 (                       # Opens CG2
     .*?                 # . denotes any single character, except for newline
                           # * repeats zero or more times
                           # ? as few times as possible
 )-                      # Closes CG2
                           # Literal -
 (                       # Opens CG3
     \d+                 # Token: \d (digit)
                           # + repeats one or more times
 )                       # Closes CG3
 \#                      # Literal #
 \.                      # Literal .
 [a-zA-Z]+               # Character class (any of the characters within)
                           # Anything between a and z
                           # Anything between A and Z
                           # + repeats one or more times
```

You haven't specified what the known prefix is, you should be careful to escape special characters in known string, especially period, plus sign, asterisk, question mark, and parentheses.